# Hibernate queries on database

Tags: mysql, database, hibernate, spring

I'm having a problem with the amount of queries done by hibernate to the database. 
Here's my query log (using Mysql 5.1) to the database when doing a simple select:

```
111125  7:18:30
27 Query    SET autocommit=0
27 Query    SELECT @@session.tx_isolation
27 Query    select this_.id as id34_0_, this_.media_id as media3_34_0_, this_.message as message34_0_, this_.user_id as user4_34_0_ from notifications this_
27 Query    rollback
27 Query    SET autocommit=1
```

I've read a lot about setting autocommit to 0 and then to 1. I know that the default for a connection is 1 and this behaviour cannot be changed. You can run SET autocommit = 0 but the result is the same.

Is there anyway to avoid any of those queries? I don't know why the SELECT @@session.tx_isolation is happening and the rollback. When I use a transaction I get a commit and then a rollback. Not sure why a rollback is always cabled.

Thanks a lot!

My conf:
Spring 2.5.6, Hibernate 3.6.0, Mysql 5.1

datasoure.xml:

```
<bean id="dataSource" destroy-method="close"
    class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />

    <property name="initialSize" value="3" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="20" />
    <property name="minIdle" value="3" />
    <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="false" />
    <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false" />
    <property name="defaultTransactionIsolation" value="4" />
</bean>
```

Transaction manager definition:

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

**UPDATE**: Managed to take out the rollback by setting new property

```
<property name="defaultReadOnly" value="true" />
```

But the problem now is that you can't make a modification (no matter if I set on the transactional annotation readOnly=false) to the db giving a SQLException. 
This property sets the connection readonly to true.
I'm guessing there's no way to do this with HibernateTemplate.

I use aspectj transaction for inner code weaving.

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true" />
```

Comment: Your transactions fails! Did you enable transaction manager in spring context? And your log is normal, mine is similar, except of rollbacks.

Comment: It's just a select and it has no @transactional annotation. It seems that everything is being treated as a transaction.

Comment: I mean native DB level: 27 Query    rollback. It rollbacks transaction. Are your Inserts or Updates working correctly?

Comment: Yes, when I use a @Transactional in a method it turns for commit or rollback if an exception is thrown. So inserts, updates and selects on a transaction work. I think somehow I'm adding overhead with that rollback on every "simple" select

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure transactions for your application.  See the [Spring 2.5.x documentation on transaction management](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/transaction.html).

Edit 12/3/11: Even for methods that only do selects, you still have to create a read only transaction in order to remove the extra queries you mentioned in your post.  Just write @Transactional(readOnly=true) and you should be good to go.

Edit 12/20/11: You also need make sure transactions are configured correctly.  It looks like the configuration you posted may be missing < tx:annotation-driven /> annotation.  See [section 10.5.1 of the Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html).

Comment: I've added the transaction manager. I use @transactional annotations when I need a transaction but in this case, there's no transaction going on.

Comment: Even for methods that only do selects, you still have to create a read only transaction in order to remove the extra queries you mentioned in your post.  Just write @Transactional(readOnly=true) and you should be good to go.

Comment: Still getting the same transaction rollback and autocommit. I get a commit also now with readonly=true

Comment: Please see my updated response: You also need make sure transactions are configured correctly. It looks like the configuration you posted may be missing < tx:annotation-driven /> annotation. See section 10.5.1 of the Spring documentation.

Comment: I use aspectj transactions. Check last part of my post. Transactions are working perfectly. Only problem is the amount of queries. I've seen that if the connection to the db is readonly, the rollback doesn't happens. But it never matters for the readonly flag of the transaction. I think that that only makes hibernate no to dirty check objects and collections.

Comment: Something isn't right.  Either your transaction configuration isn't working like you think it is, or your have transactions specified on tiny methods and not on a larger overall method that contains everything that should be in the transaction.  You should test out both:  
1. Try using <tx:annotation-driven/> instead of AspectJ to see if that makes a difference  
2. Try moving the @Transactional annotation to a higher level method, such as inside a web controller instead of down inside low level DAOs.