# Unnecessary queries in Hibernate - MySql

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, hibernate

I am using **spring / hibernate / mysql** and currently using the following settings in **spring-hibernate.xml**

I am constantly seeing ***"select @@session.tx_read_only"*** and ***"select @@session.tx_isolation"*** queries being sent to the DB mostly after select statements for actual data.

Each of these queries add like 20-25ms time and I get like 70 queries run against the DB on a Oauth login. How can I get rid of them ?

I tried statelessSessions and the queries disappeared and I could reduce the number of queries to the application queries only but I read that using statelessSessions will not provide any first-level cache and its also vulnerable to data aliasing effects.

How can I avoid the "select @@session.tx_read_only" and select @@session.tx_isolation" running multiple times.(I use a generic Dao to access the DB a extract is given below) i am using findById, findAll, getNamedQueryAndNamedParam methods...

**spring-hibernate.xml**

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${JDBC_CON_STRING}" />
    <property name="user" value="${USER_NAME}" />
    <property name="password" value="${USER_PASSWORD}" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.model" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_configuration_file_resource_path">ehcach.xml</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.auto_close_session">true</prop>
    </property>
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>named-queries.xml</value>
            <value>native-named-queries.xml</value>
        </list>
            </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="testClassDao" class="com.dao.GenericHibernateDao">
    <property name="clazz" value="com.model.TestClass" />
</bean>
```

**GenericHibernateDao.java**

```
@Repository
@Scope("prototype")
public class GenericHibernateDao<T, PK extends Serializable> implements GenericDao<T, PK> {

private Class<T> clazz;

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public void setClazz(final Class<T> clazzToSet) {
    this.clazz = clazzToSet;
}

protected Session getSession() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}

protected Session getOpenSession() {
    return sessionFactory.openSession();
}

@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public T findById(PK id) {
    Object obj = null;
    obj = getSession().get(clazz, id);
    //obj = getStatelessSession().get(clazz, id);
    return (T) obj;
}

@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public List<T> findAll() {

    String queryString = "from " + clazz.getName();
    Query query = getSession().createQuery(queryString);
    query.setCacheable(true);
    List<T> list = query.list();
    return list;
}

@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public List<T> getNamedQuery(String queryName) {
    Query query = getSession().getNamedQuery(queryName);
    //Query query = getStatelessSession().getNamedQuery(queryName);
    query.setCacheable(true);
    List<T> results = query.list();
    return results;
}

@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public List<T> getNamedQueryAndNamedParam(String queryName, String paramName, Object value) {
    Query query = getSession().getNamedQuery(queryName).setString(paramName, value.toString());
    query.setCacheable(true);
    List<T> results = query.list();
    return results;
}
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public PK save(T persistenceObject) {
    Serializable save = getSession().save(persistenceObject);
    return (PK) save;
}

@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void saveOrUpdate(T persistenceObject) {
    getSession().saveOrUpdate(persistenceObject);
}

public void saveOrUpdateBulk(Collection<T> persistenceObject) {
    Session session = getOpenSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    int i = 0;
    for (Iterator<T> iterator = persistenceObject.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        i++;
        session.saveOrUpdate(iterator.next());
        if (i % 100 == 0) {
            session.flush();
            session.clear();
        }
    }
    tx.commit();
    session.close();
}

@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public boolean delete(PK id) {
    Object findById = findById(id);
    if (findById != null) {
        getSession().delete(findById);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hibernate queries on database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271445/hibernate-queries-on-database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK to remove those extra queries, remove all your modifiers to your `@Transactional` annotations. The price you pay for restricting your isolation level to `READ_COMMITED` is that Hibernate will need to perform extra queries to determine if the database is in a dirty state. For 90% of cases, these modifiers are unnecessary. Hibernate is very good at ensuring that your data will be clean without you trying to add these restrictions.

If it is absolutely necessary for you to ensure that your isolation is `READ_COMMITTED`, you can't do anything about the extra queries.

Moving to a `StatelessSession` just to get rid of those queries is a bad idea for exactly the reason you pointed out. Really, the only valid reason to be using a `StatelessSession` is for large batch inserts of data that you know won't be read while the insert is occuring.

Comment: Thanks James, I still get **"select @@session.tx_read_only"** when I have @Transactional is there any way of fetching it initialy or forcing it so that the multiple round trip to database could be avoided ?

Comment: Do you have `@Transactional(readOnly=true)` set anywhere? I imagine that would be the cause of the above query. Otherwise, fetching session attributes would have to be redone, every time a session is opened with `@Transactional`. Thats why you usually do session management on the Service layer.