# Why am I seeing an equal number of SELECTs in MySQL Workbench, when I am only making INSERTs from a Java program?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am generating random test data and INSERT-ing them into a MySQL (8.0.20) database. I have a simple Java program that creates 100 threads, each of which will insert 100,000 records into a simple table.

**Table Description**

```
mysql> desc item;
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int          | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name  | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**DataGenerator.java**

```java
public class DataGenerator implements Runnable {
    private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/todo";
    private static final String USR = "root";
    private static final String PWD = "root";
    private static final AtomicInteger itemId = new AtomicInteger(1);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            new Thread(new DataGenerator()).start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USR, PWD)) {
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into item values (?, ?)");
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
                ps.setInt(1, itemId.getAndIncrement());
                ps.setString(2, String.valueOf(new Random().nextInt()));
                ps.execute();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I am using the MySQL Workbench Performance Dashboard to see what's happening. It shows an INSERT rate of around 18K/second. But it also shows a SELECT rate of 18K/second!

[Screenshot showing equal number of INSERTs and SELECTs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4NIV.png)

Why are so many SELECTs happening, when I am only doing INSERTs?

**Notes about the environment**

- The `todo` database is the only user created database in the server, apart from those that came with the MySQL installation.
- The `item` table is the only table in the `todo` database.
- This is my development machine and I am 100% sure that no other client is connecting to this database server.

Comment: With every `INSERT` statement, engine runs preliminary `SELECT` to make some checks. But I'm not sure about details.

Comment: Also relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24563385/java-hibernate-unnecessary-queries-on-detached-objects

Comment: @Progman yes, those links answer my question. Thank you! C̶a̶n̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶ ̶p̶o̶s̶t̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶m̶ ̶a̶s̶ ̶a̶n̶ ̶a̶n̶s̶w̶e̶r̶ ̶s̶o̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶I̶ ̶c̶a̶n̶ ̶a̶c̶c̶e̶p̶t̶,̶ ̶o̶r̶ ̶s̶h̶o̶u̶l̶d̶ ̶m̶y̶ ̶q̶u̶e̶s̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶b̶e̶ ̶c̶l̶o̶s̶e̶d̶ ̶a̶s̶ ̶a̶ ̶d̶u̶p̶l̶i̶c̶a̶t̶e̶?̶ I chose `Yes` in the blue box that appeared at the top of my question and it marked my question as duplicate automatically.

Comment: @FooMaster Not sure if you can close your own question as a duplicate, you can try.