# Hibernate does unnecessary things before executing my SELECT statement. How do I prevent these from happening?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

```
9442750 Query   /* mysql-connector-java-5.1.14 ( 
Revision: ${bzr.revision-id} ) */SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name ='language' OR Variable_name = 'net_write_timeout' OR Variable_name = 'interactive_timeout' OR Variable_name = 'wait_timeout' OR Variable_name = 'character_set_client' OR Variable_name = 'character_set_connection' 
OR Variable_name = 'character_set' OR Variable_name = 'character_set_server' OR Variable_name = 'tx_isolation' OR Variable_name = 'transaction_isolation' OR Variable_name = 'character_set_results' OR Variable_name = 'timezone' OR Variable_name = 'time_zone' OR Variable_name = 'system_time_zone' OR Variable_name = 'lower_case_table_names' OR Variable_name = 'max_allowed_packet' OR Variable_name = 'net_buffer_length' OR Variable_name = 'sql_mode' OR Variable_name = 'query_cache_type' OR Variable_name = 'query_cache_size' 
OR Variable_name = 'init_connect'
                 9442750 Query   /* mysql-connector-java-5.1.14 ( 
Revision: ${bzr.revision-id} ) */SELECT @@session.auto_increment_increment
                 9442750 Query   SHOW COLLATION
                 9442750 Query   SET NAMES latin1
                 9442750 Query   SET character_set_results = NULL
                 9442750 Query   SET autocommit=1
                 9442750 Query   SET 
sql_mode='NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'
                 9442750 Query   SELECT @@session.tx_isolation
                 9442750 Query   SET autocommit=0
                 9442750 Query   <select_statement_here>
                 9442750 Query   rollback
```

I saw these logs in my MySQL logs and I found it weird that it had to execute so much unnecessary operations before and after running my query.

For instance, it sets autocommit to 1 then eventually changes it back to 0. Also, what's up with the SELECT @@session.tx_isolation? What does it do? And lastly, why is there a rollback at the end? I'm no SQL genius but I'm sure that SELECT statements do not require either a commit or a rollback (from the developer's side at least... not sure what happens in MySQL).

What I was expecting was just my query being invoked and returned but instead I was greeted by these. Is this bad for my application and/or server? Will it use too much memory? My application isn't exposed to the public anyway - it's just used internally.

Comment: How could you retrieve the above query log ? Is it from from the database server ?

Comment: Yes it's from the database server

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24276196/unnecessary-queries-in-hibernate-mysql)